# Flag Posts help section is out of date

Tags: support, flags, privileges, help

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ["Flag posts" privilege page out of sync with recent updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75652/flag-posts-privilege-page-out-of-sync-with-recent-updates)

The information on https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts is out of date and does not contain the information about using the "It doesn't belong here" button.